# Redisson live object cant be deleted in micro service system

Tags: java, redis, redisson

Im using redisson java with redis live object to write data to redis server.
One micro service is creating live object and also set expiry to that object, and other is using that live object to execute some logic. I have noticed that when this second micro service is working on a live object while it reaches its expiry- the object inner fields are deleted BUT the main key of the redis live object does NOT.

What am I missing here? Why using redis live object in multiple programs cause this delete problem?

In this second micro service I try to use RMap  instead of Redis live object and the delete process works just fine, but I wonder if I am missing something about the correct use of redis live object: Why this delete problem is happening?